# form a var and an arrayB excluding var after bash unset on arrayA in each loop

Tags: arrays, bash

Team, need some help here as it is print index number and not actual value. I am unable to print `var`. All I want is to the expected output listed below. Given an array I want to print a var uniquely and then rest of the elements in same array to be appended to another array excluding var. because I have to use bazel coverage command using var as param1 and new array as param2 in such a way that var value is not present in skip array param2.
note:
I have commented bazel line in end to first evaluation assignments are happening or not.

```
bazel_paths_array=(a b c d)
    for ele in "${!bazel_paths_array[@]}"
    do
        b=("${bazel_paths_array[@]}")
        unset b[$ele]
        echo "${b[@]}"
        if [[ ! "${na2[*]}" =~ "$abp" ]]
        then
            var=$bazel_paths_array["${abp}"]
        fi
        na2="${b[*]}"
        printf "var to run bazel on: %s\n" "${var}"
        printf "new array to skip bazel on: %s\n\n" "${na2}"
        #bazel coverage "$var" "${na2[*]}"
    done
```

output

```
b c d
var to run bazel on: a[0]
new array to skip bazel on: b c d

a c d
var to run bazel on: a[1]
new array to skip bazel on: a c d

a b d
var to run bazel on: a[2]
new array to skip bazel on: a b d

a b c
var to run bazel on: a[3]
new array to skip bazel on: a b c
```

expected output

```
length of bazel paths array is 4:

b c d
var to run bazel on: a
new array to skip bazel on: b c d

a c d
var to run bazel on: b
new array to skip bazel on: a c d

a b d
var to run bazel on: c 
new array to skip bazel on: a b d

a b c
var to run bazel on: d
new array to skip bazel on: a b c
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `var=...` up before the `unset` and directly reference the desired element, eg:

```
for ele in "${!bazel_paths_array[@]}"
do
    b=("${bazel_paths_array[@]}")
    var="${b[ele]}"                              # new
    unset b[$ele]
    echo "${b[@]}"
#   var="${!b}" # < HOW TO DO THIS?              # old
    na2="${b[*]}"
    printf "var to run bazel on: %s\n" "${var}"
    printf "new array to skip bazel on: %s\n\n" "${na2}"
    #bazel coverage "$var" "${na2[*]}"
done
```

This generates:

```
b c d
var to run bazel on: a
new array to skip bazel on: b c d

a c d
var to run bazel on: b
new array to skip bazel on: a c d

a b d
var to run bazel on: c
new array to skip bazel on: a b d

a b c
var to run bazel on: d
new array to skip bazel on: a b c
```

**NOTES:**

- while the last `printf` mentions 'new array' and then displays `na2` ...
- `na2` is not an array; `na2` is a string
- if `na2` needs to be an *array* then consider replacing `na2="${b[*]}"` with `na2=( "${b[@]}" )`

Comment: Awesome. I am going to try and mark solution. Thank you much!!